# Unable to mock GAE userservice

Tags: google-app-engine, automated-tests, junit4

I am trying to mock the gae user service for writing unit tests and couldn't get the following code to work.

My test class is as below.

```
public class AuthenticationTest {

    private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
        new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalUserServiceTestConfig())
            .setEnvIsAdmin(true).setEnvIsLoggedIn(true)
            .setEnvEmail("test@example.com");

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        helper.setUp();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        helper.tearDown();
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsAdmin() {
        UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
        assertTrue(userService.isUserAdmin());

        String email = userService.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
        assertEquals(email, "test@example.com");
    }
}
```

I find that userService.getCurrentUser() always returns null.

Most of the code is taken from the example in [developers.google.com](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting#Writing_Tests_with_Authentication_Expectations). The only thing I added is call to .setEnvEmail("test@example.com")

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Sathya

Comment: Is your `@Before` method being run?

Comment: Yes, i put a break point and confirmed that the @Before method is being run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in order to mock email, the auth domain also needs to be mocked, just add

```
.setEnvAuthDomain("example.com");
```

to your helper initialisation or in @Before method post initialise and it will work fine.

hope it helps